# Error 500/fatal error: Class 'Jhtml' not found

Tags: templates, joomla, error-handling, joomla3.1

I'm struggling to improve my Joomla website.

I'm getting a **500 error** when I try to open my articles in the front end, so I changed the error reporting to "Developed". I then received the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Jhtml' not found in /xxx/components/com_comment/templates/default/default.php on line 49
```

How to I prevent this error from occuring?
Could someone also point out a good free template website if the problem lays in me changing the template?

Comment: As this is coming from `com_comment` which belong to a 3rd party extension, you would be better of contacting the developers of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to Update your Comment component. I had the same problem after an update to Joomla 3.1.5. Download the latest version of the comment component and just install it (if no other instruction for an update are given by the developer of the component).